# How to test assert whether two lists of dictionaries (where a dict item contains a list) are the same

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, python-unittest

I'm creating my first test script (yay!) I'm have a list of dictionaries where one of the keys is a list. I'd like the test to past if the list (in the dictionary) is in any order. I know you can use `assertCountEqual` to check list equality regardless of order, but can you do that for a list that contains a dictinary of lists? See below for example

Will Succeed

```
def test(self):
    output = [2,1]
    desired_output = [1,2]
    self.assertCountEqual(output, desired_output)
```

Will Fail

```
def test(self):
    desired_output = [{'count': 2, 'columns': ['col2', 'col5']}]
    output = [{'count': 2, 'columns': ['col5', 'col2']}]
    self.assertCountEqual(output, desired_output)
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you need to be using lists inside your dictionary? If order is unimportant, why not switch to sets?

Comment: You could try sorting each list.  Whenever you diff things a lot - in unit tests or not - sorting is always something to consider.  @dspencer - duplicates would drop out in a set leading to false equalities.

Comment: good call @dspencer. I don't need to be using lists. Sets would also work for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The `assertCountEqual(first, second, msg=None)`:

> Test that sequence first contains the same elements as second,
>   regardless of their order. When they don’t, an error message listing
>   the differences between the sequences will be generated.

### Important:

Calling `assertCountEqual(first, second, msg=None)` is equivalent to calling`assertEqual(Counter(list(first)), Counter(list(second)))`.

### Note:

A Counter is a dict subclass for counting hashable objects. It is a collection where elements are stored as dictionary keys and their counts are stored as dictionary values. 
For this to work the keys have to be `hashable` but unfortunately the `dict` is `unhashable` because its mutable.

---

In order to perform the desired task you could use the `frozenset`.
**The `frozenset` builds an immutable unordered collection of unique elements.** In order to have the test succeed you will have to build a dict whose values corresponding to its keys are immutable. We can use the recursive approach to build a dictionary that contains immutable values.

**Try this (UPDATE):**

```
def getHashableDict(dictionary):
    hashable_dict = {}
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        if isinstance(value, list):
            hashable_dict[key] = frozenset(value)
        elif isinstance(value, dict):
            hashable_dict[key] = getHashableDict(value)
        else:
            hashable_dict[key] = value

    return frozenset(hashable_dict.items())

def test(self):
    desired_output = [{'count': 2, 'columns': ['col2', 'col5']}]
    output = [{'count': 2, 'columns': ['col5', 'col2']}]

    output = [getHashableDict(item) for item in output] #--> create list of hashable types
    desired_output = [getHashableDict(item) for item in desired_output]

    self.assertCountEqual(output, desired_output)
```

**The test will now succeed.**

Comment: In modern (3.6+ for CPython/PyPy, 3.7 as language guarantee) `dict`s are insertion-ordered by default; `Counter` inherits this behavior, so it's not unordered as you say; the keys are ordered by when they were first seen while counting.

Comment: Clever! @dspencer pointed out that sets would work equally well in this scenario. At least in my use of it it does. However, this also solves the issue and I learned something. Thank you!